# Cold Engine warm up

Tags: starting, ram

Is starting a cold engine and driving a very short distance and turning the engine off worse than letting the engine idle to warm up?

Comment: How short is "very short?" Two or three car lengths, so you are not blocking someone else? 100 yards/meters? Half a mile? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about doing this regularly? If so, neither will do the engine much good!  Engines need to be up to operating temperature to work effectively-too many short, or very short trips will do it no good in the long run